# How can I create a variable in SAS containing Ridit scores for each observation?

Tags: syntax, sas

I have a variable which is a sum score ("fsum") and I need to calculate weighted ridit scores for each observation and save it as a new variable to allow me to use the ridits as a continuous variable in other analyses.

I tried using an out statement on the proc freq syntax, but of course it just saved the frequencies, not the ridit scores (see below)

```
proc freq data = ftest;
    weight dataset_weight;
    tables fsum / out = ridits scores = ridit;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide example input data and wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the RIDIT row scores using ODS OUTPUT.  `FREQ` `TABLES` statement option `SCOROUT` tells the procedure to create ODS OUTPUT that includes ODS table name `rowscores`.

This example code creates two data sets `work.freqdata` and `work.riditscores`, the first is from `FREQ` `TABLES` statement, the other from an `ODS OUTPUT` statement:

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 100;
    do test = 1 to 6;
      grade = 60 + ceil(40 * ranuni(123));
      array ws (6) _temporary_ (0.15, 0.15, 0.10, 0.15, 0.10, 0.35);
      W = ws(test);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

ods noresults; * prevent actual ODS destination generation, but still create ODS output tables;

ods output rowscores=work.riditscores;  * capture the desired ODS output table;

proc freq data=have;
  weight W;
  tables grade*test 
  / scores=ridit 
    all
    scorout
    out=freqdata
  ;
run;

ods results;
```

Not sure if this is wisest, but transpose into one row with new columns named `ridit_for_<score>`.

```
proc transpose data=riditscores out=ridit_across prefix=ridit_for_;
  by table;
  id grade;
  var score;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. This is just producing a dataset saving the output from the proc freq. What I need is for the ridit score for each observation to be stored as a variable (i.e., there should be one score for each observation) - I hope that makes sense!

Comment: (by "saving the output" there I meant it produces a summary table, not saving the value for each observation)

Comment: Transpose the output to get one row.

Comment: Sorry - on looking closer your first answer was correct. (I was not understanding correctly what I was aiming for) Thanks for your help!